# google sheet : extract column Name from address

Tags: google-sheets

I try to get the column name from cell address, for example :

```
AB123 --> AB
X90 --> X
```

When using address(), it will return in $COL$ROW format. I want to get rid the $ symbol and the number/row and just need that column name.

Also using column() i can get the index, not the name.

How can i do it in quite simple way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Address, but set the row number to 1 and use option 4 to remove $ signs:

```
=substitute(address(1,column(AB123),4),"1","")
```